# Higher Order Estimation Errors

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, soft-question, parameter-estimation

I well know estimation measure is the so called minimum mean square error (MMSE) defined as:
\begin{align}
E[|W-\hat{W}(V)|^2]
\end{align}
where $W$ is a random variable (that we want to estimate) and random variable $V$ is the observation based on which we use estimator $\hat{W}(V)$ to infer what $W$ is.

MMSE is a well know quantity and received a lot of attention for the following reasons (not an exhaustive list):

- it is easy to analyse analytically
- MMSE is the $L^2$ norm and therefore it is a Hilbert space and estimator $\hat{W}$ is interpreted as a orthogonal projection
- MMSE also has an interpretation of energy of the error

My questions are the following.

Do other estimation error 
\begin{align}
E[|W-\hat{W}(V)|^p]
\end{align}

for $p \in \mathbb{R}$ have

- some 'advantages'(open to interpretation) over MMSE?
- arise  naturally in some applications?
- has anyone studies these higher order errors and for what purpose?
- any thing else that you can think of?

Please feel free to edit and improve the question.

**Edit:**

1. See the comment by A.S. where he notes that $p=1$ is also commonly used.
2. Also, $p=\infty$ which is the essential supremum, would correspond to the maximum possible error. It may or may not exists depending on what $X$ and $Y$ and $\hat{W}(Y)$.

Comment: $p=1$ is certainly used (the minimizer is the median of $W$) and is more robust to outliers and uncleaned data.

Comment: @A.S. Thanks. Just to clarify, is it the median of  $W \sim p_{W|V}$ instead of a median of  $W \sim p_W$? If you could, can you put it as an answer maybe with some references to $p=1$?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_absolute_deviation. Once you have data $V$, only $W|V$ matters, so it would be the median of that.